# Is there a better way to write a method that returns an iterator?

Tags: rust

I have a structure called `Finder` that searches for a word in a list of strings:

```rust
fn main() {
    let lines = vec![
        "The first line.",
        "And the second one.",
        "The very last line.",
    ];
    let word = "the";
    let iter = lines.iter().map(|x| String::from(*x));

    let finder = Finder::new();

    for matched in finder.find(iter, word) {
        println!("{:?}", matched);
    }
}

pub struct Finder {
    ignore_case: bool,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Match {
    line_no: usize,
    offset: usize,
    line: String,
}

impl Finder {
    pub fn new() -> Finder {
        Finder { ignore_case: true }
    }

    pub fn find<'a, I: 'a>(
        &'a self,
        lines: I,
        word: &'a str,
    ) -> impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = Match> + 'a
    where
        I: std::iter::Iterator<Item = String>,
    {
        let word = String::from(word);

        lines
            .enumerate()
            .filter_map(move |(i, line)| match self.find_word(&line, &word) {
                Some(index) => Some(Match {
                    line_no: i,
                    offset: index,
                    line: String::from(line),
                }),
                None => None,
            })
    }

    fn find_word(&self, line: &str, word: &str) -> Option<usize> {
        if self.ignore_case {
            line.to_lowercase().find(&word.to_lowercase())
        } else {
            line.find(word)
        }
    }
}
```

I would say that this implementation is much more *indirect* than it should be, but I would like to better explore available language's features.

The method `find` takes an iterator, and returns the iterator that yields `Match` results. The code works as expected, but feels quite complex! The `find` method's signature includes templates, lifetimes, and other things that look quite tricky to me as a newcomer.

Is there a better way to return an iterator from a method? I could implement the same logic using simple functions and structures, or just call `filter_map` on vector, but my goal is to get a better grasp of the language's capabilities.

Is it possible to return an iterator from a method, but have a *simpler* method's signature, or is it expected to have such a "verbose" signature in this case?

This code was written with the compiler's assistance, i.e., I fixed errors one after another until it worked. Would a Rust professional write this in the same way, or there is a better way?

Comment: You can reduce some verbosity by avoiding the fully-qualified paths and by using `impl trait` as an argument: `pub fn find<'a>(&'a self, lines: impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a, word: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = Match> + 'a`. You don't need a lifetime on `word` because you create an owned `String` from it.

Comment: [Some possible cleanups](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2444c7d12d72897bc75ce9b8a01ab642)

Comment: @Shepmaster that's great, thank you very much! Especially for the possible cleanup suggestions!